# How to pull out values from a dictionary into an array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

```
spades = ['2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','10S','JS','QS','KS','AS']
hearts = ['2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','10H','JH','QH','KH','AH']
clubs = ['2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','10C','JC','QC','KC','AC']
diamonds = ['2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','10D','JD','QD','KD','AD']
allCards = spades + hearts + clubs + diamonds

import random
random.shuffle(allCards)

bot1 = [allCards.pop() for i in range(2)]
print(bot1)
cardVal = {'2S':1,'3S':2,'4S':3,'5S': 4,'6S':5,'7S':6,'8S':7,'9S':8,'10S':9,'JS':10,'QS':11,'KS':12,'AS':13,
    '2H':1,'3H':2,'4H':3,'5H': 4,'6H':5,'7H':6,'8H':7,'9H':8,'10H':9,'JH':10,'QH':11,'KH':12,'AH':13,
    '2C':1,'3C':2,'4C':3,'5C': 4,'6C':5,'7C':6,'8C':7,'9C':8,'10C':9,'JC':10,'QC':11,'KC':12,'AC':13,
    '2D':1,'3D':2,'4D':3,'5D': 4,'6D':5,'7D':6,'8D':7,'9D':8,'10D':9,'JD':10,'QD':11,'KD':12,'AD':13}

for i in bot1:
    print(cardVal[i])
    bot1hand = [cardVal[i]]
print(bot1hand)
```

I want to put the values of the cards that `bot1` owns in a separate array, but am running into an issue. I always get the two values printed on separate lines and the array `bot1hand` only stores the last value of the two.

For example:

```
>>> 
['AC', '5C']
13
4
[4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
for i in bot1:
    print(cardVal[i])
    bot1hand = [cardVal[i]]
print(bot1hand)
```

In particular this line:

```
bot1hand = [cardVal[i]]
```

You are constantly writing over your values because you are not actually properly appending to your list. In fact, your bot1hand is not being considered a list.

What you want to do first is initialize it as a list outside of your loop:

```
bot1hand = []
```

Then inside your loop, use the append method on it:

```
bot1hand.append(cardVal[i])
```

So your final chunk of code should look like this:

```
bot1hand = []
for i in bot1:
    print(cardVal[i])
    bot1hand.append(cardVal[i])
print(bot1hand)
```

As a final refactoring step in your code, you can actually do what @NathanielFord has suggested, is use a comprehension (which I see you already used in your code, so you must be already familiar with it). That chunk of code I have in this answer can now be reduced to this:

```
bot1hand = [cardVal[i] for i in bot1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is the problem. You may want to try a list [comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
bot1hand = [cardVal[i] for i in bot1]
print(bot1hand)
```

(I'm assuming the print statement is for debugging purposes.)

To list comprehension handles the responsibility of actually building the list for you.